# Time averaged delta function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Suppose a Dirac delta function shifts horizontally as $\delta(x - a \sin(\omega t))$, could we define a "time average" of it like
$$
f(x) = \frac{\omega}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi/\omega} \delta(x - a \sin(\omega t)) dt
$$
? What would be the function look like? It is--I think--equivalent to
$$
f(x) = \frac{\omega}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi/\omega} \delta \left(t-\frac{1}{\omega}\arcsin(x/a) \right) dt
$$
It is tempting to argue that if $t=\arcsin(x/a)/\omega$ for a $t$ in $(0, 2\pi/\omega)$, and the integration becomes $\omega/2\pi$. But I think it is wrong. The reason is the integration bound is chosen arbitrarily: any bound with a gap of $2\pi/\omega$ should do.

Comment: Why not refer to the definition of the delta function (which is not a function, as you know), and see what happens?

Comment: @Did I don't know the most fundamental distribution definition. Regarding the physicist's definition (infinite pulse at 0 and integration to 1), I pointed out that the integration bound can be adjusted, which confuses me.

Comment: But you have to have **some** definition. What does it say? Please include this to the question. (Note that "infinite pulse at 0" does not qualify for a mathematical definition.)

Comment: @Taozi Physicists $\texttt{do not}$ set a definition as you claimed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirac delta is a distribution, which means that it is a linear functional acting upon the space of test functions. The same is true for $f$. That said, if you want to recognize $f$, then you can first apply $f$ to test functions.

Now if $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is a test function, then (by abusing notations to denote the distribution-function pairing by the usual integral notation) we find that

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x)f(x) \, dx
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \left( \frac{\omega}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi/\omega} \delta(x - a\sin(\omega t)) \, dt \right) \, dx \\
&= \frac{\omega}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi/\omega} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \delta(x - a\sin(\omega t)) \, dx \right) \, dt \\
&= \frac{\omega}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi/\omega} \varphi(a\sin(\omega t)) \, dt \tag{1} \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{\varphi(x)}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} \, dx. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

The computation $\text{(1)}$ tells that your integral is just a disguise of the following familiar-looking linear functional

$$ \varphi \quad \mapsto \quad \frac{\omega}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi/\omega} \varphi(a\sin(\omega t)) \, dt. $$

Moreover, $\text{(2)}$ tells that $f$ can be identified with the following function

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} \mathbf{1}_{[-a,a]}(x). $$

This is not surprising, since you are building up $f$ by summing up infinitesimal masses.

Comment: Hi, that's a great answer with a surprising result. One question though is the integral bound from (1) to (2). A direct change of variable $a\sin(\omega t)\rightarrow x$ changes both the bounds to 0. So did you shift the bounds in (1) to something like $(-3\pi/2\omega, pi/2\omega)$ beforehand?

Comment: @Taozi, Exactly. Also you have to split integrals into two parts where $t \mapsto a\sin(\omega t)$ becomes monotone and hence the substitution makes sense.